# How to show Array of Strings from Assets on Recyclerview list?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

im new to software coding and i'm trying to make an app on Android Studio that lists all of my files from the assets folder and show them in a Recyclerview. Right now it shows me the items that i put manually into "myListData" ("Email", "Info", "Delete", etc.. but i want it to show me automatically every item in the assets/gpcs/ folders (those items are listed in the "listofassets" string) and it only show them if i put the "[numerofasset]" of each one. Sorry if this is too obvious.

This is my MainActivity

```
package madrigal.gpcsinfecto;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
       String[] listofassets = assetManager.list("gpcs");
        String[] filelist = assetManager.list("");
        if (filelist == null) {
            // dir does not exist or is not a directory
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
                String filename = filelist[i];
            }


            MyListData[] myListData = new MyListData[]{
                new MyListData(listofassets[0], android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email),
                new MyListData("Info", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info),
                new MyListData("Delete", android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
                new MyListData("Dialer", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer),
                new MyListData("Alert", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert),
                new MyListData("Map", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map),
                new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email),
                new MyListData("Info", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info),
                new MyListData("Delete", android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
                new MyListData("Dialer", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer),
                new MyListData("Alert", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert),
                new MyListData("Map", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map),

        };
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);;
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(myListData);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


};

}
```

This is MyListAdapter class

```
package madrigal.gpcsinfecto;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private MyListData[] listdata;

// RecyclerView recyclerView;
public MyListAdapter(MyListData[] listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MyListData myListData = listdata[position];
    holder.textView.setText(listdata[position].getDescription());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(listdata[position].getImgId());
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+myListData.getDescription(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    }
    }
}
```

MyListData class

```
    package madrigal.gpcsinfecto;

public class MyListData{
    private String description;
    private int imgId;
    public MyListData(String description, int imgId) {
        this.description = description;
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getImgId() {
        return imgId;
    }
    public void setImgId(int imgId) {
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `new MyListData(listofassets[0],` . You already put the name of the first file in your model. (Does that code compile?) What is the problem to make a loop where you put every file name in a myListData[]?

Comment: MyListData[] myListData = new MyListData[listofassets.length]; Then make the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does compile when i put the name of the first file but i want to add every item inside the folder without me having to put the number of file (the '[0'). What do you mean with making the loop?

Comment: Make a new `for` loop. Where you loop throug all items.